# How to plug a BIRT datasource query builder to a connection pool?

Tags: datasource, jndi, connection-pooling, birt

Usually when creating a standard JDBC datasource in BIRT Eclipse designer, we can define both a direct JDBC access and a JNDI uri for connection pooling. Thus in development mode the designer makes use of a direct-access, and when deployed in production (Tomcat) the JNDI connection pool takes precedence:

[image]

It works very well, but now i would like my users to take advantage of the JDBC query builder, in order to design queries graphically.

However when creating a new datasource => "JDBC Database connection for query builder", the configuration screen does not allow to enter a JNDI uri:

[image]

I tried in "optional" tab to set manually a property such "odaJndiName=java:comp/env/mydatabase" but it does not help it breaks the datasource.

Is it possible to plug a BIRT "JDBC connection query builder" to a connection pool when deployed in a production context?

Thanks!